# how a derived class pointer can call the base class function

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have a base class 'a' which includes some virtual function , in the derived class 'b' i overload that function . Now I have one more class 'c' derived from 'b' only and I have a pointer to class c .But I am not able to figure out how to call that function from the 'c' class pointer . Help me out , maybe its stupid but I am stuck here .

Answer (score 1):

```
struct A { virtual void foo() {} };
struct B: A { void foo() override {} };
struct C: B {};

auto main() -> int
{
    C o;
    C* p = &o;

    p->foo();    // Calls B::foo
    p->A::foo(); // Calls A::foo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `c` is the pointer to `C`:

```
c->A::method();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints 
and To be more specific I am working on Qt (c++ gui library) and in that I have a connect function which is like this
connect ("C class pointer", SIGNAL(A class FUNC) , another ptr , SLOT(func)) ;
now i am just using this func and it is givin me the error that FUNC is not in C class 
is there any solution to this ...